# Can I pass a list to os.getenv()?

Tags: python, linux

I'm cooking a new python script for our constant integration plateform based on Hudson/maven/nexus etc.

To do so, I've to check some environnement variables before starting anything on my script, so I planed to use the getenv() function of the OS module.

I've used it many time as a single shot to check a limited set of variables as described on the python's documentation:

[Python os.getenv() Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-parameters)

On this documentation, they said that os.getenv() **"will return the value of the envrionnement variable *varname*"**, but they didn't said if we can or cannot pass multiple varname values.

For now, I use a FOR wheel to check them all, I'm sure that a dict comparison would be more effective and I'll work on it on the second review of the code.

So if you already test to pass multiple argument to the getenv() function I'll be happy to hear you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use os.environ. I'm not sure about what you want to do exactly, but I'll give you an example:

```
wanted_envs={'HOME':'', 'USER':'', 'BANANA':''}
for env in wanted_envs.iterkeys():
    if env in os.environ:
        wanted_envs[env] = os.environ[env]
```

Comment: Yes, That exactly what I do currently, I just thought that maybe the getenv() variable would rather accept a multi-values argument :D

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome. But I don't think that getenv would rather accept many arguments.

Comment: What a pity! It would be usefull to be able to have something like:
***MyListOfElement=['apple','pinapple','express']
os.getenv(MyListOfElement)***

Comment: You could try with `map(os.getenv, MyListOfElement)` or `dict(zip(MyListOfElement, map(os.getenv, MyListOfElement)))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, the map solution look sexy for me (Just saw the doc about it), I'll give it a try tomorrow morning ;-)